# Ubuntu Sendmail Not Sending Emails

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, sendmail

This is the second painful day of trying to get PHP's mail() function to work, last night I had it working but sendmail would automatically send everything to spam, saying it was sent via localhost.localdomain - so I wiped sendmail and tried a few other clients, no luck.

Reinstalled sendmail and here we are again - nothing is being sent but PHP is giving no error.

Here's a bit of my error log from /var/log/mail.err

```
Jul 27 09:06:04 server1 sm-mta[10620]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): opendaemonsocket: daemon MTA-v4: cannot bind: Address already in$ Jul 27 09:06:04 server1 sm-mta[10620]: daemon MTA-v4: problem creating SMTP socket
```

Another error is

```
Jul 27 09:05:39 server1 sm-mta[10654]: u6R95d9B010654: SYSERR(root): collect: Cannot write ./dfu6R95d9B010654 (bfcommit, uid=0$
```

"server1" isn't the hostname, it was my hostname lastnight but it was since changed to "cruisetouch" - running the hostname command shows the hostname to be "cruisetouch", so why it's showing "server1" is also a mystery.

Any help in fixing these errors or recommending an easier alternative (just want to send OUTGOING MAIL for things like password resets, I use "Zoho" at the moment and have it synced to domain i.e info@cruisetouch.com not info@zoho.com).

I don't have postfix installed anymore, and port 22 seems clear, but I'm not 100% sure how to make sure that it is.

Please help.

Comment: `ss -lntp` will show you what process is listening on which port.
Also port 22 is for SSH, port 25 is for SMTP server. So that's more port 25 that you should make sure is free.
Maybe try to restart sendmail daemon so it takes your new hostname into account ?

Comment: What's the restart command for sendmail daemon? @pat

Comment: Got it, 6 emails just came through spam when I restarted it. You're a legend @pat

Comment: Good to know that it worked. :)